# Como clonar de um repositório no Bitbucket usando um código bash e passando o password como parâmetro?

Tags: git, bash, clone

Tenho um código bash que cria uma instância de um servidor na AWS.
O último passo desse processo é fazer o clone do projeto que se encontra no `bitbucket.org`.

Normalmente o que eu faço manualmente são esses passos:

1. `cd $HOME/vhosts`  - me posiciono dentro da pasta onde eu quero clonar o repositório
2. Clonar - `git clone https://myusr@bitbucket.org/myusr/prjct.git`
3. O password solicitado. Digitar password.
4. Apertar o btn enter.
5. O clone foi efetuado com sucesso.

Para o processo ficar automatizado preciso pular os passos 3 e 4.

Queria saber se tem alguma maneira de automatizar esse processo sem usar ssh.
Não existem opções para passar parâmetros na função [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que tenha que alterar algo no .git/config. Mas encontrei estes sites na internet que podem te ajudar:

https://coderwall.com/p/_plhoa/no-password-git-push-on-bitbucket

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600652/git-on-bitbucket-always-asked-for-password-even-after-uploading-my-public-ssh

Comment: na verdade a resposta esta no no segundo link.  `http://username:password@bitbucket.org/...` deu certo. Edite sua resposta.